# Erro de "headers already sent" ao criar tabelas na ativação de plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin para WordPress, no qual durante a ativação, duas tabelas que se relacionam devem ser criadas. Meu código está assim:

```
function create_tables(){
    global $wpdb;
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    // Query para a criação da tabela de parceiros.
    $sql_partners = "CREATE TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."partners(
                    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    name VARCHAR(355) NOT NULL,
                    phone VARCHAR(12),
                    address VARCHAR(355) NOT NULL
                    );";

    dbDelta($sql_partners);

    // Query para a criação da tabela de categorias. Parceiros são agrupados por categoria.
    $sql_categories = "CREATE TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."partner_categories(
                      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                      name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                      FOREIGN_KEY (partner_id) references partners(id)
                      );";

    dbDelta($sql_categories);
}
```

Esta função já está devidamente configurada no `register_activation_hook` do plugin. A primeira tabela é criada. Mas a segunda, ao que parece, é simplesmente ignorada e tenho o seguinte erro na tela de ativação:

> Este plugin gerou 875 caracteres de saída inesperada durante a ativação. Se encontrar mensagens de “headers already sent” problemas com feeds ou outros, tente desativar ou remover o plugin.

Já tentei várias coisas, entre elas mudar a codificação do arquivo. Simplesmente nada funciona. Alguém já passou por isso e saberia me dizer o que está errado aí?

Comment: Não manjo muito de SQL então não sei a solução, mas o problema é sua segunda query. Não sei de onde sai o `partner_id` e o `REFERENCES` devia apontar para a outra tabela **com** prefixo (está sem na query). O error log do PHP mostra os erros.

Comment: Além do erro apontando pela @brasofilo, aparentemente a  função *dbDelta()* pode não estar conseguindo analisar sua query. Segundo o [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) pelo que pude ver: 1) A definição da PRIMARY KEY deve ser "atrasada", isto é, feita após a definição dos campos. 2) Os tipos dos campos devem ser escritos em letras minúsculas.

Comment: A pate que você destacou em amarelo ja é parte da resposta pra pergunta. Seu plugin gerou uma mensagem de saída, que provavelmente é composta por erros e avisos. Olhando o _log_, como mencionado pelo @brasofilo, você provavelmente vai ter a explicação, ou no mínimo uma noção do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Isso se estiver habilitado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além do mais você colocou `FOREIGN_KEY (partner_id)` e deveria ser o `id` da mesmo tabela, ou seja, `FOREIGN_KEY (id)`. E como os colegas falaram, você esqueceu o prefixo ao fazer a `FOREIGN KEY`.  Tente deste modo:

```
function create_tables(){
    global $wpdb;
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    // Query para a criação da tabela de parceiros.
    $sql_partners = "CREATE TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."partners(
                    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    name VARCHAR(355) NOT NULL,
                    phone VARCHAR(12),
                    address VARCHAR(355) NOT NULL
                    );";

    dbDelta($sql_partners);

    // Query para a criação da tabela de categorias. Parceiros são agrupados por categoria.
    $sql_categories = "CREATE TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."partner_categories(
                      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                      name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                      FOREIGN_KEY (id) references ".$wpdb->prefix."partners(id)
                      );";

    dbDelta($sql_categories);
}
```